# How to display a quote in django template

Tags: python, django

Passing `"'2015/07/01'"` to a django template is rendering this character when queried in my browser: `&#39;2015/07/01&#39;`.

I would need to have `'2015/07/01'` (that's to include it into a javascript function, and my browser doesn't interpret it as `'2015/07/01'` but sets it to `&#39;2015/07/01&#39;` in the javascript).
How could I print `'2015/07/01'` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try default django template tag `safe`. This can be used as follows:

```
{{your_date|safe}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing data to JavaScript, use json.

Comment: Fair, but how could you still print '2015/07/01' in the browser source code?